# How to monkey patch Array in Rails lib subfolder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching

I have a standard Rails 5.2 application and I would like to add a method to an `Array` class.

So I have created a file in `lib/core_extensions/array/use_slugs.rb` with this code:

```
module CoreExtensions
  module Array
    def use_slugs
      binding.pry
    end
  end
end

Array.include CoreExtensions::Array
```

and in my `config/application.rb` file I have added:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
  config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib', 'core_extensions', '**/')
  ...
end
```

But still when I call `[].use_slugs` I get `undefined method 'use_slugs' for []:Array`

Why?

Thanks

Comment: did you try without `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib', 'core_extensions', '**/')`

Comment: yes (didn't help), but my guess is you need it

Comment: Can keep it in an initializer, if that's okay with you.

Comment: well, sure (and it is working), but it's definitely not a place such code should be..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for someone else. I have decided no to load the entire `lib` folder in the `application.rb` file at all, because generally you don't want to load all rake tasks etc. (so I have deleted the `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` and `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib', 'core_extensions', '**/')` lines from `application.rb`)

I have kept the folder structure in the `lib` folder same, but I'm loading only particular files and `lib` subfolders in the `config/initializers/lib_init.rb` file I have created, like this:

```
require Rails.root.join('lib', 'sp_form_builder.rb')
Dir[ Rails.root.join('lib', 'core_extensions', '**') ].each { |f| require f }
```